# avr-g++ compilation failed with Make Error 1

Tags: eclipse, makefile, arduino, avr, avr-gcc

I'm trying to compile Arduino code in Eclipse. Below is the build log.

```
make all 
Building file: ../test.cpp
Starting C++ compile
"/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=163 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR     -I"/opt/arduino-1.6.3/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino" -I"/opt/arduino-1.6.3/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard" -I/usr/lib/avr/include -MMD -MP -MF"test.cpp.d" -MT"test.cpp.d" -D__IN_ECLIPSE__=1 -x c++ "../test.cpp"  -o  "test.cpp.o"
as: unrecognized option '-mmcu=avr5'
make: *** [test.cpp.o] Error 1
```

What's wrong? What does `as: unrecognized option '-mmcu=avr5'` mean? It can't recognize the `-mmcu` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is coming from the assembler `as`. The AVR assembler `avr-as` does accept the `-mmcu` option. Perhaps Eclipse is choosing some other `as` instead?

Using `"/bin/avr-g++"` in the makefile looks suspicious to me. I would think that you should set up Eclipse to look for the toolchain in the right place without having to specify the directory in the makefile command.

Comment: Yep. Thanks, man. Changed path to `/opt/arduino-1.6.3/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++`.